# Change image in center of page when hover on text next to it

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image

I can see similar questions have been asked but I cannot figure this out.

I am working on this page in wordpress where there is a series of 6 questions and an image of a compass in the middle. I want the compass image to change so that when a question is hovered on a different image of the compass is shown that is pointing to the question.

The page is here: http://wearecreativecreatures.com/2016/what-do-we-offer/#questions

I have seen a version of this online but seems unnecessarily complicated: http://leiperscreekgallery.com/artists/

I am hoping to do this using CSS only. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide us a fiddle for your problem

Comment: What have you tried so far ? I never look external link. Please share your code :D

Comment: Hi, it will be more complex if we try to do this using only css. A little bit of javascript actually makes it very easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want CSS you'll want something like this (I'll leave the styling to you)

But there are ways to do this with pure JS (so no libraries needed) that might make it easier to develop.

```css
.image-container {
  border: 25px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.image-text {
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.image-text:hover {
  background: #eee;
  border-color: #333;
}
.image-text.leaf:hover ~ .image-container {
  background-image: url('http://www.balitaza.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Neem-Leaves.jpg');
}
.image-text.grass:hover ~ .image-container {
  background-image: url('http://mitchtrale.com/endlessgrass/images/grass5.jpg');
}
.image-text.forest:hover ~ .image-container {
  background-image: url('http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTYwMFgxNjAw/$(KGrHqF,!jcFC3rBNy3PBQwnG-Wy9g~~60_35.JPG');
}
.f-left {
  float: left;
}
.f-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<span class="image-text leaf f-left" href="#">Leaf!!!</span>
<span class="image-text grass f-left" href="#">Grass!!!</span>
<span class="image-text forest f-left" href="#">Forest!!!</span>
<span class="image-text forest f-right" href="#">Forest!!!</span>
<span class="image-text grass f-right" href="#">Grass!!!</span>
<span class="image-text leaf f-right" href="#">Leaf!!!</span>

<div class="image-container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help so far. I have made my first fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/stuart79/t5vgq6sv/ The html I just copied and pasted from wordpress so there's loads of classes in there that were added by the theme. The CSS is my interpretation of @Andrew's demo above.

Comment: Also I am not using javascript as I cannot seem to get it to work inside wordpress but am open to suggestions. thanks so much for your help so far!